# How can I get all buttons from a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I try to get all buttons from a `UIView`. I tried this code but it's not working.

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]
    {
        NSLog(@"found a button!");
        subview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        subview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        [subview.layer setCornerRadius: subview.frame.size.width/2.0f];
        NSLog(@"button.tag = %ld", (long)subview.tag);
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: *"it's not working"* is not an appropriate problem description. What does it do, what would you expect, provide something close to an MVCE. If you *"can't understand how it works"* how did you come up with the code or did you just copy it from another SO post without thinking about it?

Comment: print your subviews and check once

Comment: Hey luk I didn't copy this code and I am junior so i m trying to improve myself in ios. In my question, I want to give border color and corner radius to all button in one method not manually.Means take one button and give borderColor and radius and then select another one.It's increasing my code.That's why I posted this question

Comment: self.view.subviews returns subview of self.view and it wont return if the buttons are in another containerview. Eg. You cant get the button if self.view.anotherview.button1

Comment: Can you share screenshot of storyboard?

Comment: Oh, thanks Rajesh i understand what you explain I made mistake in my code.I took so many views in super view so i need to get all the view from super view and after that, I can get buttons or labels from particular subviews.

Answer (score 6):

Use this Code:

```
- (void)getAllButtonFromView:(UIView*)view {
    for (UIView* subview in view.subviews) {

        if (subview.subviews.count > 0) {
            [self getAllButtonFromView:subview];
        }        
        else if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            NSLog(@"found a button!");
            subview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
            subview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
            [subview.layer setCornerRadius: subview.frame.size.width/2.0f];
            NSLog(@"button.tag = %ld", (long)subview.tag);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem maybe is that your buttons are not directly added to your view, infact they are added in the subviews of the view. So just check if the view in subview in view.subviews are having the subview that contains the UIButton.

Answer (score 3):

> > Swift solution 4.0+

```
func getAllButtonFromViewRecursion(view: UIView)  {

    for insideView in view.subviews {
        if insideView.subviews.count > 0 {
            getAllButtonFromView(view: insideView)
        }
        else if (insideView.isKind(of: UIButton)) {
            insideView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            insideView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            insideView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        }
    }
}
```

> Objective C solution

```
- (void)getAllButtonFromViewWithRecursion:(UIView*)view {

    for (UIView* insideView in view.subviews) {

        if (insideView.subviews.count > 0) {
            [self getAllButtonFromView:insideView];
        }        
        else if ([insideView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            NSLog(@"found a button!");
            insideView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
            insideView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
            [insideView.layer setCornerRadius: subview.frame.size.width/2.0f];
            NSLog(@"button.tag = %ld", (long)subview.tag);
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Matloob, please explain your code. He was also asking for an explanation to the problem and would like to understand how it works.

Comment: yes sure , actually this code will only check single further UIview , if he found UIview with in subviews than he try toget button in further UIView , If there are are more than 1 view hierarchy in self.view than we need to use recursion.So please update me if you have more than 1 view in  hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 5.2

```
for subview in self.view.subviews {
    if subview is UIButton {
        let button = subview as! UIButton
        // do smth with a button
        button.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```